# How do I sort this Array of objects using Vanilla or lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I have this object returned to me through an angular HttpClient Observable.

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": [
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29688772",
    "name": "Demoliner/Middelkoop v Behar/Escobar",
    "countryCode": "AR",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-08T20:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
},
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29691591",
    "name": "Bemelmans v Pellegrino",
    "countryCode": "FR",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-09T09:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
},
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29690566",
    "name": "Diez v Emil Ruusuvuori",
    "countryCode": "NL",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-08T13:14:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
},
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29690822",
    "name": "Koepfer v J Rodionov",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-08T18:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
},
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29691586",
    "name": "Basic v Vanni",
    "countryCode": "FR",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-09T09:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
},
{
  "event": {
    "id": "29691596",
    "name": "P Kotov v Mayot",
    "countryCode": "FR",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "openDate": "2020-02-09T09:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "marketCount": 1
}
```

I want to sort the array by openDate.

I was thinking to do it in the subscription like so

```
getTennisMatches() {
this.betfairService.getTennisMatches().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.matches = data;
  this.sortedMatches = this.matches.sort((a, b) => (a.result.event.openDate > b.result.event.openDate) ? 1 : -1);
  // OR
  this.sortedMatches = _.sortBy(this.matches.result, o => o.result.event.openDate);
});
```

}

Both sort methods are not working with errors
 `this.matches.sort is not a function` for vanilla or
 `Cannot read property 'event' of undefined` for lodash

I think I have to iterate over the events but I'm not sure what I'm doing. I'm using lodash because I find it's syntax easier to understand but I don't have to use it. Thanks

Comment: The array is `this.matches.result`, not `this.matches`.  And your sort comparator function should return a number, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I thought it was returning a number either a 1 or a minus 1. Sorry I'm a bit confused.

Comment: 1. it doesn't return `1` or `-1` but `1` or `0`. 2. Even then, you have to return *three* values, not two. It's important to know if two items are *equal*. [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sorting the `matches` object, you could sort the `result` array inside the object.

```
this.matches.result.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a.event.openDate) - Date.parse(b.event.openDate));
```

But do note that this will also sort the original object.

Simplified example snippet:

```js
let matches = {
result : [
  { id:1001 , event: { openDate : "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z" } },
  { id:1002 , event: { openDate : "2020-02-01T20:00:00.000Z" } },
  { id:1003 , event: { openDate : "2020-02-03T20:00:00.000Z" } },
  { id:1004 , event: { openDate : "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000Z" } },
  { id:1005 , event: { openDate : "2020-02-02T20:00:00.000Z" } }
]
};

let sorted = matches.result.sort((a, b) =>  Date.parse(a.event.openDate) - Date.parse(b.event.openDate));

console.log('original object after sort', JSON.stringify(matches));
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.matches.sort is not a function` indicates that your variable `this.matches` is empty and you are trying to iterates over it so first you have to check your response from the MS call. Can be retrieving an empty array.

type instead of 'any' will be helpfully for your propose to check in case that it works and retrieve some data but they do not have the expected format.

Can also check 'Network' section in Chrome dev tool to watch the response.